# html5 video does not play from localhost

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

The mp4 video does not play from localhost.

But mp3 audio works.

i.e.

Following code for playing video (stored as C:\inetpub\wwwroot\video\testVideo.html) does not work when accessed through (http://localhost/video/testVideo.html)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <body>
    <video width="400" controls>
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

But, following code for playing audio (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\audio\testAudio.html) works when accessed through (http://localhost/audio/testAudio.html)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <body> 
    <audio width="400" controls>
      <source src="audip.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </audio>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

However, they both work when webpage is launched by double clicking on html file i.e. webpage is accessed through (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/audio/testAudio.html) or (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/video/testVideo.html)

Please explain what am I doing wrong. And how to make video play from localhost.

I am using following browsers:

```
IE 11.0
Chrome 44.0
Firefox 40.0
```

Comment: Try it with VirtualHost.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out.

The video doesn't play via localhost, because IIS localhost in Windows doesn't contain MIME type entry (video/mp4) for .mp4 file format.

To make this work, a MIME type entry should be added in following way:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Select your machine from Connection panel
3. From middle panel, double-click 'MIME Types'
4. Right-click on the list and select 'Add' option
5. Add file extension and MIME type e.g. for MP4 videos, file extension: .mp4 and MIME type: 'video/mp4'

Thats it.

Now refresh your page and Bingo!. It works.